# How do I instantiate a new bean in a method call?

Tags: java, spring, instantiation

I have something like this:

```
@Controller
@Scope("session")
public class MyServletController {



    @Autowired
    private QueryRunner queryRunner;

    HashMap<String, Result> resultsMap; 

    @RequestMapping("/submitQuery")
    public ModelAndView submitQuery(HttpServletRequest request)
    {
    String sessionId = request.getParameter("sessionId");
    Result r = queryRunner.runQuery(sessionId, request.getParameter("otherdata"));
    resultsMap.put(sessionId, r);
    }



    @RequestMapping("/getResult")
    @ResponseBody
    public void saveTextLinks(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException
    {
     String sessionId = request.getParameter("sessionId");      
     //return sessionId result from resultsMap
    }

 }


<bean id="queryRunner"
    class="com.myproject.QueryRunner"
    scope="prototype">
    <aop:scoped-proxy />


    <property name="errorMessageA" value="${error.messagea}"></property>
    <property name="errorMessageB" value="${error.messageb}"></property>

</bean>
```

What I want is that the Servlet Controller is session scoped, but each request needs to instantiate a new `QueryRunner` as to not have any interference if multiple requests are sent at once.

How do I configure Spring to do this?

The tempting solution is to just go:

```
    @RequestMapping("/submitQuery")
    public ModelAndView submitQuery(HttpServletRequest request)
    {
    queryRunner = new QueryRunner(); //<-----
    String sessionId = request.getParameter("sessionId");
    Result r = queryRunner.runQuery(sessionId, request.getParameter("otherdata"));
    resultsMap.put(sessionId, r);
    }
```

Comment: What's wrong with what you currently have? `scope="request"` is probably more fitting, but is useless unless you are using the `QueryRunner` in some other piece of code as well.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis scope=request isn't suitable as the Controller needs to hold data for later queries. Will edit to show.

Comment: Request scope for the `queryRunner` bean not for the `@Controller` bean.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Just having a look at this now. How does that work, as `QueryRunner` isn't an Servlet Controller - it's just plain java class. How does Spring know to instantiate it?

Comment: That's a broad subject. In short: it uses reflection.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I might have a different question - could you quickly look at this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31418750/will-the-same-singleton-bean-be-used-by-every-instance-of-the-owning-class

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Alright, thanks heaps for you help. Can I suggest you post an answer outlining that : 1) both prototype and request scope will generate an new instance. 2) a short summary (or a just link) saying how it does that? 

As it turns out the case here the problem wasn't the scoping on the QueryRunner, but its objects, which were all singleton scoped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [...] but each request needs to instantiate a new QueryRunner as to not have any interference if multiple requests are sent at once

Your setup already does that. Your `QueryRunner` bean is declared as

```
<bean id="queryRunner"
    class="com.myproject.QueryRunner"
    scope="prototype">
    <aop:scoped-proxy />
```

This means that Spring will inject a proxy wherever such a bean is requested, for example

```
@Autowired
private QueryRunner queryRunner;
```

and the proxy will, internally, delegate all calls to newly initialized beans every time. Note that this means that if you do something like

```
Result r1 = queryRunner.runQuery(sessionId, request.getParameter("otherdata"));
Result r2 = queryRunner.runQuery(sessionId, request.getParameter("evenmoredata"));
```

each of those `runQuery` calls are, underneath it all, invoked on different `QueryRunner` instances.

If you want to have a single `QueryRunner` bean that spans the entire lifecycle of a request, just declare the bean to have the request scope

```
<bean id="queryRunner"
    class="com.myproject.QueryRunner"
    scope="request">
    <aop:scoped-proxy />
```

Behind the scenes (assuming the default MVC configuration), Spring will store a reference to the `HttpServletRequest` in a `ThreadLocal` context accessible through a `static` utility class. It will store the actual bean in the `HttpServletRequest` attributes.

When you eventually invoke `runQuery` on the proxy (which is stored in the `@Autowired field), Spring will first check the context for a existing bean. If it finds one, it will use it to invoke your method. If it doesn't, it will initialize a new instance, store it in the context, then use it. This way, the previous example

```
Result r1 = queryRunner.runQuery(sessionId, request.getParameter("otherdata"));
Result r2 = queryRunner.runQuery(sessionId, request.getParameter("evenmoredata"));
```

is actually invoking `runQuery` on the same `QueryRunner` instance.

Since `HttpServletRequest` attributes are cleared after each request, so will your request-scoped bean instances.